# google recaptcha React js

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

I have a problem of the google recaptcha not rendering in the page at first however when i submit and the request sends me to another page and i return to the form page using arrow back on the browser it renders when i reload the page it no longer renders:

this is my index.html: `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

This is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef  } from "react";
import LogoBig from "../../../Assets/LogoBig.png";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import {
  validateEmail,
  validatePassword,
} from "../../../Components/FormValidation";
import { MdKeyboardArrowDown } from "react-icons/md";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

const UserRegister = () => {
  const [nom, setNom] = useState("");
  const [prenom, setPrenom] = useState("");
  ...
  const [recaptchaValue, setRecaptchaValue] = useState("");

  const handleRecaptcha = (value) => {
    console.log("reCAPTCHA value:", value);
    setRecaptchaValue(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    if (e && typeof e.preventDefault === "function") {
      e.preventDefault();
      const token = recaptchaValue;
      console.log('tokenCaptcha', token)
      recaptchaValue.reset();
    }
    const formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.append("nom", nom);
    formData.append("prenom", prenom);
    ...
    formData.append("recaptcha", recaptchaValue);
    formData.append("profile", "Unfinished");

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data !== "Email already in use") {
          console.log("success");
          //window.location.reload();
          //window.location.href = "/confirmation";
        } else {
          if (data === "Email already in use") {
            setRegisterError("Cette adresse e-mail est déjà utilisée");
          } else {
            setError(data);
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      });
  };
 
    <ReCAPTCHA
      sitekey={"6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"}
      onChange={handleRecaptcha}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be use only one attribute on the `<script>` because when you use both attibutes `async` and `defer` the only one that works is defer by hierarchy.

**Async** is executed immediately after script is downloaded.

**Defer** is executed after HTML parsing is complete.

In your case, maybe you need use `async` alone.